# JApplet: getAppletContext().showDocument() with POST-Data?

Tags: post, redirect, applet, document, show

i have to develop a java-applet which redirects to another webpage. Normaly i use the "showDocument(URL ul)"-method to do that. But in this case i have to send a lot of data to this page. So i need to do it via POST. But showDocument just allows GET-method.

My question: Is it possible to do a redirect to another webpage from within a japplet AND to send POST Data in the same request (like showDocument() but with POST data)? - I know that i can do a POST request from within the applet - but this will happen in the applet's context.

It's a bit complicated because the script from which the applet is called, runs on a client-auth protected server. So i need to do the requests with the browser (because he will be authenticated) - if i do these requests from within the applet, the applet have to authenticate again...

thanx
daniel

Answer (score 1):

Directly with the Java Applet API this is not possible - `showDocument` is the only thing you have, and it supports only GET. You may be able to do something like this with the JavaScript bridge (i.e. call javascript functions from the applet, which then send the POST request to the server like the browser would (and show the result in a new browser window), but I never used this.

Comment: thank you for the answer. this is a solution i thought about. but we try to avoid the use of javascript.